# How to remove the modifier from accesskey

Tags: php, javascript, html, accessibility

Is there a way to account for all known OS/Browser combinations and have a single accesskey input for a link tag, without the modifier?  As noted in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key)  I can have accesskey="d" and I know some users will input Alt+d some Alt+Shift+d.  Is there a way around this?  How can I allow a user to just enter "d"?  Is this poor design or misplaced intent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> How can I allow a user to just enter "d"?

Attach an event listener on the document for all keypresses, doing particular things for the keys you want to pay attention to.

> Is this poor design or misplaced intent?

Poor design, unless you want to go hoop jumping.  Think of input fields.

Keep in mind that different platforms have different accesskey requirements *because of how the platform works*.  For example, Alt+C on one platform might map to Ctrl+C on another, which might end up being "copy to clipboard" in addition to whatever else your page might want to do, and that could have unintended consequences.